# sinonjs mock with dependency injection

Tags: mocking, javascript, qunit, sinon

I've turned some code into a library and want to unit test it with qunit and sinonjs

```
var modalDialogHandler = function( constructorOptions ){
    "use strict";

    var call = {};

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // attach modal dialogs to all links that are children of elements with this selector
    var enable = function( selector ) {
        jQuery( document ).on( 'click', selector, function( event ) {
            call.displayModalDialog(this);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    };

    var displayModalDialog = function(element) {}

    var inject = function (functionToReplace, injectedFunction) {
        call[functionToReplace] = injectedFunction;
        return injectedFunction;
    }

    call = {
        init: init,
        enable: enable,
        displayModalDialog: displayModalDialog,
        inject: inject
    };
    return call;
}
```

Using a spy to test this works:

```
var m = new modalDialogHandler();
m.enable('.modal_dialog');

m.inject('displayModalDialog',this.spy());


jQuery('.modal_dialog').each( function (){
    this.click();
});
equal(m.displayModalDialog.callCount, 2,'successfully attached');
```

However, how can I use mocking? I tried to inject the mocking function this way

```
var m = new modalDialogHandler();
var myAPI = { displayModalDialog: function () {} };
var mock = this.mock(myAPI);

var displayModalDialog = m.inject('displayModalDialog', myAPI.displayModalDialog);
mock.expects(displayModalDialog).twice();

jQuery('.modal_dialog').each( function (){
    this.click();
});
mock.verify();
```

I'm sure I will need mocking for the more complex parts of the library

Comment: Why is `inject()` necessary?  Why not `sinon.spy(m, 'displayModalDialog')`?  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/sYuAL/

Comment: Hi, the idea was to make most of the class function private. I know there is a school of thought out there to not unit test any private functions, but that doesn't help us reduce regression issues. I have actually managed to test most of the class using spies, but I would be interested if mocks can be used with some sort of "private" functions implementation